# ASP.NET MVC: jQuery UI DatePicker Set minDate and maxDate from Model on AJAX Loaded Page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a dialog form that pops up and its content is loaded using the jQuery load function.  On that ajax loaded page there is a jQuery UI datepicker and in the Model that I pass to the view, I have MinDate and MaxDate properties that are used to set the min and max dates of the datepicker.  On a non-ajax page I usually do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
     var model = @(Model.ToJson());

        $('.date').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(parseInt(model.MinDate.substr(6))));
        $('.date').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', new Date(parseInt(model.MaxDate.substr(6))));

});
</script>
```

The problem is that if I include any javascript in the view that is loaded from the jQuery load function, it is stripped out and not executed.  So, if I included the above code to specify the min and max dates for the datepicker in the dialog form doesn't work.

How can I specify min and max dates for a jQuery UI datepicker where the datepicker is being loaded via ajax and the min and max dates come from the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could serialize those two model properties as HTML5 data-* attributes somewhere in the DOM. For example as part of the datepicker itself it would be great:

```
<input type="text" class="date" name="myDate" data-min="@Model.MinDate" data-max="@Model.MaxDate" />
```

and then define some functions:

```
function initPicker() {
    $('.date').each(function() {
        $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', $(this).data('min'))
               .datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $(this).data('max'));
    });
}
```

and then invoke this function in your DOM ready:

```
$(initPicker);
```

as well as in your AJAX success callbacks in order to reattach them.

Comment: I had thought of that and it was going to be my solution if there wasn't any other way to do it.  Sounds like this might be the best thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
var minshowdate = new Date(@(DateTime.Now.Date.Year), 
                           @(DateTime.Now.Date.Month), 
                           @(DateTime.Now.Date.Day));
$('#ShowDate').datepicker({ minDate : minshowdate });
```